# variable and function scope inside javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I am trying to build up a super primitive cue function. Essentially need to repeat an operation n number of times.

```
var serialCue = {
  init:function(length_of_cue, handler){
    this.length_of_cue = length_of_cue;
    this.handler = handler;
    //this.handler();
    var index = 0;
  },
  monitor: function(){
    console.log(this.index);
    // this.handler();
    // this.index++;
    // if(this.index>=this.length_of_cue){
    //   this.handler();
    // }
  },
  eachIteration: function(callback){
    console.log("yo");
    callback();
  },
  startProcessing: function(){
    for(var count=0;count<this.length_of_cue;count++){
      this.eachIteration(this.monitor);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Object.create(serialCue);

//IN APP.JS
var cue = require('./serial_cue.js');

cue.init(5,function(){
  console.log("done done and done!");
});

cue.startProcessing();
```

The output returns "undefined" for the value of the index. I am trying to figure why "this" behaves predictably within all of the methods defined for this object except monitor. Still a little shaky with scopes in JS.

Comment: index is a local variable in your init() function. You should also look into the .bind() function:  this.eachIteration(this.monitor.bind(this)).

Comment: @nnnnnn but changing it to this.index = 0; produces the same result

Comment: True, because there is a second part to the problem, hence my mention of .bind(). See the answer below. [MDN's `this` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) may also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function as `functionName()`, rather than as the method of some object, like `object.functionName()`, its `this` value will default to `undefined` in strict mode, and the global object in "sloppy mode".

Two options here are:

Bind the function to `this` before passing it into your method:

```
this.eachIteration(this.monitor.bind(this));
```

Or if you want the callback in `eachIteration` to always have the current `this` as its `this` value, you can use the callback's `.call()` method:

```
callback.call(this);
```

---

Another issue is that `index` is a local variable inside your `init` method and it disappears as soon as `init()` finishes executing. If you want your object to have an `index` property, make it a property:

```
var serialCue = {
    index: 0,
    init:function(length_of_cue, handler){
.....
```

Comment: Put together a quick gist based on solutions suggested. https://gist.github.com/Digi-D/7de9ad7952c0b07f9d5d   thnx!